# Prove that the orthocentre of a certain triangle is on the side of another triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

This geometry question has been frustrating me for a week:

> Let ABC be an acute angled triangle with circumcenter O. A circle passing through A and O intersects AB, AC at P, Q respectively. Show that the orthocentre of triangle OPQ lies on the side BC.

---

My observations and ideas:

1. We can try to prove O is the circumcenter of PQH. But we may need a
   different description of H.
2. If H is the orthocentre, we can see that triangle PQH is similar to
   triangle ABC (in some order).

I suspect that there is a unique triangle PQX with X on BC and triangle PQX similar to triangle ABC if I put some additional condition. Then using that condition I can try to show O is the orthocentre. I have not been successful so far.

Answer (score 4):

Nice problem! I'll omit some details, but feel free to ask clarifications.

First of all, let us call $\alpha=\angle BAC$ and $\beta, \gamma$ the other two. Using that $APOQ$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, we have that $\angle QPO=\angle QAO=\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta$, and similarly $\angle PQO=\frac{\pi}{2}-\gamma$.

Now, take the circunference through $O, P, B$, and let $R$ be the intersection with the side $\overline{BC}$. [It is not so difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miquel%27s_theorem) to check that $CQOR$ is a cyclic quadrilateral (and is an excellent excercise if you haven't done it before). This allows us to compute the angles
$$ \angle RPO=\angle OQR=\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha. $$
In particular, this shows that $\overline{PO}\perp \overline{RQ}$ and $\overline{QO}\perp \overline{PR}$, showing that $R$ is the orthocenter of $PQO$.

[image]

Comment: I have taken the liberty to include a (Geogebra) figure in order to follow more easily the proof.

Comment: OK! Never realised this property of Miquel points.